# Rest API - Is it safe to get password in JSON response

Tags: json, node.js, rest

I'm writing a Rest API with Node.js and using JWTs.

I have the route below to authenticate users.

I'd like to ask, the `user` that is returned from the method `User.findOne` returns the correct password hence I'm able to check if its correct. 
However is this safe to do? I did a console.log and it shows the password (albeit encrypted) but still feels unsafe as someone could surely view?

```
router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {

  // find the user
  User.findOne({
    name: req.body.name
  }, function(err, user) {

    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
    } else if (user) {

      // check if password matches
      if (user.password != req.body.password) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
      } else {

        // if user is found and password is right
        // create a token
        var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
          expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
        });

        // return the information including token as JSON
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Enjoy your token!',
          token: token
        });
      }

    }

  });
});
```

Comment: No. Furthermore, it's not safe to store the password on your server. You should do authentication on the server with a secure hashing mechanism so that the original password is never stored. There's some good information on the topic here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19525/help-understanding-basic-user-authentication-with-salts-and-hashing And here: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: we are doing a similar thing in our current project and we had no issues thus far. For us the JWT token generated remains in the browsers cache. One more thing to add is that our application is internal to the organisation.

Comment: The problem isn't that you are passing the password somehow, the problem is that you need to have to unencrypted somewhere to be able to pass it. And this is usually a bad idea already.

Comment: @userMod2: please see my latest edit. I added some technical aspects you'r most probably interested in as well. Also make sure to up-vote & accept if my answer was satisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Furthermore, passwords shouldn't be saved *encrypted* in the database, but *hashed*. The classical environment saves passwords for example as md5 (more common) or bcrypt (more secure) hash.

This ensures that even if your database gets stolen, no one will have the passwords of your users; there is no way to "decrypt" the hashes (not in a hundred million years).

When a user logs in you compare a hash of the entered password with the hash assigned with the user. You can use great modules like [bcrypt-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs)

**EDIT**

From a technical aspect it wouldn't be dangerous. When you start your server JavaScript compiles your code and executes the result in a V8 engine. There is no way to access whats ever returned by your database as long as the connection between node and MySQL is save.
One could possibly dump the servers memory and hope to find the right bits. But if someone gains the necessary permissions, you'r doomed either way.

I implemented an example for you, it's untested, but should show you how it's meant.

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
        if (!err) {
            var newUser = new User({
                name: req.body.name,
                password: hash
            });

            newUser.save(); // ????
        }
    });
});
router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
        name: req.body.name
    }, function(err, user) {
        var password = 'GP%Z!zvbk/9>Ss-R';
        var passwordHash = '$2a$10$W.zZPCaNOuR152I4qENKH.8h7I6BPcfCYBJqHPNXbVaBz0XWVxnBm'; // bcrypt of string ')RZK&M(QX"k188cw'

        if (user) {
            password = req.body.password;
            passwordHash = user.password;
        }

        bcrypt.compare(password, passwordHash, function(err, success) {
            if (success) {
                var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
                    expiresInMinutes: 1440
                });

                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Enjoy your token!',
                    token: token
                });
            }
            else {
                res.status(401).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Authentication failed.'
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note: bcrypt uses random salt by default for each hash operation. This means, whenever you hash a given input, it will produce different hashes each time. The salt is then stored as part of the hash which can be verified then. Please check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) for further info.

Comment: Thanks - so the hashing bit makes sense. However what would the flow be. User enters their username + password. Do i then send username + hashed password and check it matches on the server before sending a true or false?
If so how about sending the hashed password is that ok through https.

Comment: Two options: Either you hash the password on the client and compare it directly or *and only if you have HTTPS* send it plain and hash it on the server. If someone intercepts the traffic and gets the hash, this person could also replay the hash to get access. So better use HTTPS and don't care about the rest ;)

Comment: And sure, after comparison, send either response to indicate success.

Comment: So this means i need to write some more code that sits on my server that reads this? would node again be used for this?

Comment: Yes. Please read my answer again; I added a link, they provide you with almost everything you need to implement (*REALLY* straight forward).

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that it's not a good idea to respond differently to whether the user does not exist or the password is wrong. If you do, it's trivial to enumerate users until you find correct usernames. If you respond the same way (`401 Unauthorized`) the attacker don't know which is wrong. For this reason, you may want to compare with a placeholder password in the case the user wasn't found, so the time spent serving the request is also the same.

Comment: Really nice and useful thoughts, @LinusGustavLarssonThiel, thank you!

Comment: In respect of your suggestions I edited the code again and added the security requirements you mentioned. Still any concerns? =)

Comment: Thanks for the kinds words. I think it looks good -- of course you could always use the `req.body.password`, regardless of whether there is a matching user or not. Also, I'm not sure about bcrypt but it might work to just compare against the empty string.

Comment: This is fantastic. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: So to finally confirm the hashed password comes back in the user variable from `function(err, user) {` so if someone could view the response its hashed so my users are safe? Also technically could someone trying to view responses actually do so?

Comment: Please read my answer carefully. Both aspects are well covered.

Comment: Sorry - all clear. I see in the above you just used var password as an example, I guess in reality i'll send a hash password on the client side then send hashed to server/api.

Comment: What?! NO. You send the password from the client as plaintext to the server (you are behind HTTPS!). Then, on the **server** you use `bcrypt.compare()` to validate the plain input is represented by the hash stored in the database. The client only sends over the data, you verify it on the server. Thus, it'll never be a security issue.

Comment: @userMod2: to be clear: yes, you could do so. But you'd need a client side bcrypt library which might have a few dependencies and thus produce heavy load on your client. As already said; please use HTTPS :)) Just curiosity wise: did you succeed so far?

Comment: Yes - with your great instructions all pretty much setup. And I've gained an good overall awareness of key concepts to look out for around auth security. Again your help appreciated.